# Default Name value in Lightning

Tags: lightning, button-overrides, default-value

We are currently using an s-control override on the New button to provide a default value for the Name field on various custom objects. For lightning experience, we have to replace this functionality with a different kind of override. I know that I can provide initial values via lightning actions, but this means having to create a button for each record type, and also won't replace the new button on list view pages, etc.

How are other people handling this? We have a temporary workaround of a visualforce page that then calls sforce.one.createRecord() (Summer '17 can pass in default values), but as I asked [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/176678/detect-when-user-clicks-cancel-on-createrecord-modal), this creates some problems of its own.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
sforce.one.createRecord()
```

?

It has been significantly improved with Summer'17 and now you can even add default values. Plain and simple, you can use it like this one-liner:

```
sforce.one.createRecord('Opportunity',null,{ 
    Name : "2017-10-01 - Power Corp. - Big Deak - 999k",
});
```

**From the Summer '17 Release Notes - [Prepopulate Fields on a Record Create Panel](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_vf_defaultfieldvalues.htm)**

> Speed up record creation with prepopulated field values. The sforce.one.createRecord function now includes `defaultFieldValues` (optional) so you can define fields on a record create panel, including fields not displayed on the panel. This change applies to Lightning Experience and the Salesforce1 mobile browser app.
>
> Users must have create access to prepopulated fields. Errors during saving that are caused by field access limitations do not display error messages.

**Caution 1:**

The this feature from Summer'17 works only if you put your Visualforce Page to API v40.0 or higher.

**Caution 2:**

Objectnames and Fieldnames are CASE-SENSITiVE! So `name` is not `Name` and only `Name` is correct

**See also:**

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/salesforce1_dev_jsapi_sforce_one.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_createRecord.htm